# Maven fails to find local repo artifact

Tags: maven

I am getting this:

```
Failed to execute goal on project boot: Could not resolve dependencies for project xxx:boot:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact xxx:xxx:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT in central (http://xxx/artifactory/all/) -> [Help 1]
```

That arifact is ONLY in my local repo.  (Yes I can see it there)  Maven is not picking up.

I see alot of ideas on SO but none of them have worked.

I have tried all of the sugestions on SO:

```
find ~/.m2/repository -name _maven.repositories -exec rm -v {} \;

find ~/.m2/repository -name _remote.repositories -exec rm -v {} \;
```

I deleted the repo and re-built (ie. mvn install)  all the needed dependencies.

I added

```
<snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
</snapshots>
```

to the POM

I tried mvn -o install

I am not sure what to try next!  I am using mvn 3.3.9 on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: looks like you can't not download xxx:xxx:jar from http://xxx/artifactory/all/.check you settings.xml,is that a legacy url?can you ping it?

Comment: Maybe I was not clear.  That jar is not in the remote articatory.  It only exists locally.  Maven is not looking there.

Comment: are you sure the target jar file located in the repository? xx.jar and the xx.pom should be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your information, I would say you might have to run the full command (especially for jars built before the 2.5 version of Maven), which should be (replace with what's convenient): `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
    -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>`

See: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `localRepository` tag in your `settings.xml` actually points to the m2 repository location on your machine. You will find settings.xml in `%M2_HOME%/conf` directory

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run a maven build for a child project which is dependent on another parallel level child project. Just run a maven build on the parent project once.It resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

for me , it was a multimodule maven project and the parent module's version didn't match the versions of the child modules. And so apprently the project didn't install well